# Ship a python project

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have worked on a Python 3.6 project which I want to ship to a client. 
I have tried 'Cx_freeze' to create an executable file of the project but it throws as error as displayed in the screenshot below.
[image]

Is this the best way to distribute python code ?

Comment: I recommend to use https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **pyinstaller**

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

once installed,

```
pyinstaller myprogram.py
```

there is alternate,

http://www.py2exe.org/

but pyinstaller simple and better than others

Comment: I had used pyinstaller but it doesnt seem to work well with python 3.6

Comment: Getting the following error,

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: pyinstaller supports latest python version from 2.7, 3.4+

Comment: I haven't used recursion in my code. I have resolved my query and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this. I had 2 issues.

1)RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

I added the below lines to the beginning of the spec file and saved it.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

And ran pyinstaller test.py again.This solved my problem and the package was built successfully.

2)After the executing the exe, the command screen would just open and close straight away.
I used `pyinstaller -c -F test.py`
where -c is to keep the command window open and -F is to package all files into one executable.